# Can a 2GP managed package depend on a BETA release 1GP managed package?

Tags: beta-managed-package, 2gp, package-dependency, 2gp-ama

We are creating a new "extension package" for our AppExchange 1GP that integrates it with a third-party managed package and want to use 2GP for this "extension package". The third-party is willing to share an installable beta release of their 1GP with us along with its installation password (that way they know we can't use it on production orgs, just for our integration package development).

Do you know if it is possible to create our 2GP with a dependency on that beta release, or do we need them to also share the equivalent full release's version ID with us? I'm hoping one or other can be used, with us installing the beta 1GP on our scratch org to satisfy the dependency. Would this work?

I've searched for detail around this but can find nothing - the [Salesforce documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev2gp_config_file.htm) focuses on the simple use cases as always... :(

Comment: Could you share what you ended up doing for this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vendor of the 1GP made the installation key (package password) available for only a beta release of their product. Using this as the dependency for the 2GP we developed (to extend the third-party package) worked absolutely fine. We could install a (later) non-Beta release version of the third-party package on a sandbox and on production and then install and use our 2GP extension package successfully.

Obviously it is important that any actual usages the 2GP makes of the 1GP's metadata is compatible between the beta and the full release later employed in sandbox/production.